# monit send alert for different cycles fails to different e-mail addresses

Tags: alert, cycle, monit

how can I set alert for different cycles fails to different users (something like that) for the same service in monit?

I have tried the config like his below.

```
check host "Cluster0 Admin Panel" with address 192.168.5.80
          if failed port 4443 protocol https with timeout 10 seconds for 3 cycles then alert userA@mydomain.com
          if failed port 4443 protocol https with timeout 10 seconds then alert userB@mydomain.com
```

But syntax error occured on the e-mail addresses lines.

this one sent emails to both user at 1th cycle and 3th cycle

```
check host "Cluster0 Admin Panel" with address 192.168.5.80
          if failed port 4443 protocol https with timeout 10 seconds for 3 cycles then alert 
                alert userA@mydomain.com
          if failed port 4443 protocol https with timeout 10 seconds then alert 
                alert userB@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how Monit handle the alert statement, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Setting-an-alert-recipient

You can set the alert target (a email) using the global "set alert" statement or the "alert" statement in the context of a service entry. But you can not set a email address in a context of a test. You can check the behaviour by using "monit -v" to get some Monit internal information about the configuration.

```
Remote Host Name      = Cluster0 Admin Panel
 Address              = 192.168.5.80
 Monitoring mode      = active
 On reboot            = start
 Port                 = if failed [192.168.5.80]:4443 type TCP/IP protocol HTTP with timeout 10 s using TLS then alert
 Port                 = if failed [192.168.5.80]:4443 type TCP/IP protocol HTTP with timeout 10 s using TLS for 3 cycles then alert
 Alert mail to        = userB@mydomain.com
   Alert on           = All events
 Alert mail to        = userA@mydomain.com
   Alert on           = All events
```

This looks like this, based on your sample.